# Pop up bubble messages for boot related issues

Tags: notify-osd, notify-send, systemd-journald

I was looking at one of my apps today and wondered if it actually worked to get today's sunrise and sunset times. Conky displays them as 8:46am and 4:36pm respectively but they could be yesterday's times for all I know. I could dig through program code and find what error messages go into `journalctl` if program failed and then manually search for those error messages.

It would be easier if there is an existing app where I put in what messages to watch for and it checks `journalctl` for me. Then it sends a pop-up notification periodically until I acknowledge reading it.

As a bonus the program can keep track of the times a specific error has occurred in a scroll-able database. Maybe for some errors such as NTFS permissions which spam `journalctl` just the count per day, week, month, etc is better and no pop-up notification.

Is there such a program already or do I have to invent the wheel?

Comment: Your mention of conky (and sunrise and sunset)  gives the impression of a specific requirement but later it appears you want to be notified whenever particular entries, not necessarily conky, are written to journalctl.

Comment: @DKBose That is is just one example of what someone might want to know. I also want to know how many NTFS permission errors were generated because at one point it seemed like thousands per day. Someone else might be interested in nVidia error messages, NVMe error messages or Thunderbolt error messages in `journalctl` whatever floats your boat. Just a simple app that scans journalctl for what you are interested in and sends you a pop up bubble on desktop GUI periodically until you acknowledge you read the message.

Comment: @K7AAY Please read above ^^^ It's not just about sunrise and sunset that was just a simplistic example of something the system could tell me is broken.